# Error installing rails-4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, osx-mountain-lion

Using `OS X 10.8.4` and `ruby 1.9.3p194`

```
$ gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-4.0.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-4.0.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-4.0.0...
ERROR:  While generating documentation for rails-4.0.0
... MESSAGE:   error generating /Users/michaelirey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/doc/rails-4.0.0/rdoc/guides/Rakefile.html: Error while evaluating /Users/michaelirey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/page.rhtml: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (RDoc::Error)
... RDOC args: --op /Users/michaelirey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/doc/rails-4.0.0/rdoc lib --title rails-4.0.0 Documentation --quiet
```

Looks like this is just for the documentation, but it would still be nice to get things installed without error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try updating rdoc, it may just be old.

```
gem update rdoc
```

Comment: Doesn't rdoc get installed along with Ruby? He has Ruby 1.9.3, which should work fine with Rails 4.0 right?

Comment: Surely, but it gets updated like any other gem, and Rails 4 is newer than Ruby 1.9.3, so who knows...  That patchlevel of Ruby 1.9.3 is well over a year old.  I agree with just skipping the docs altogether, but he asked. :)

Comment: From the official webpage: "Rails 4 prefers Ruby 2.0 and requires 1.9.3 or newer." Not saying that your solution won't work, but it surely doesn't make sense to me :)

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc - Yes I would prefer to use Rails 4 with Ruby 2.0. However I am stuck with ruby 1.9.3 for other reasons.

Answer (score 17):

Can't tell you where that error comes from, but considering how useless installing ri and rdoc actually is, I would just do:

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

You'll also get a much faster install by skipping the docs. In fact, this is what the official release page recommends: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/6/25/Rails-4-0-final/

Comment: Good to know. Didn't really need the rdocs anyways, but since Nick answered my question he gets the accepted answer.